# React Functions Passing Props with Function and Const

Tags: reactjs, function, constants

What is the difference between passing props with function and with const?

Comment: Add more details and give examples.

Comment: interesting question. to the child component idk if there is any difference i am not sure if hoisting comes into play with how props are defined and passed but at the level they are defined hoisting comes into play... nothing i think you would ever see but am interested to see what other ppl with more experience say :)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that react do comparisons on your props to figure out if it needs to be re-rendered.

The values you return from a function call will always be new values.
Therefore react will needlessly re-render the child component (the one receiving props from a function) whenever the parent is re-rendered.

Depending on how the parent declares the const props. They may also be new values which will cause re-renders anyway or a reference/pointer to existing values.